# Alternate Results with ORDER BY clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
  customername varchar(50)
);

INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('CUSTOMER 1');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('CUSTOMER 1');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('CUSTOMER 1');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('CUSTOMER 2');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('CUSTOMER 2');
INSERT INTO TEST VALUES('CUSTOMER 2');

SELECT * FROM TEST ORDER BY ???
```

What ORDER BY clause should I put to get the following result ?:

```
"CUSTOMER 1"
"CUSTOMER 2"
"CUSTOMER 1"
"CUSTOMER 2"
"CUSTOMER 1"
"CUSTOMER 2"
```

Comment: You could probably come up with some hideous monstrosity involving server-side vars, case/if structures, etc... but... why? What would happen if you've got 3 customers? 4? 5?

Comment: Add an additional `sequence` field to your table that dictates the sequence...

Comment: I sense you'd be better rethinking the database design and what you want to achieve with it.

Comment: Haven't got a postgres instance to test with but I believe recent versions support ranking functions so you could order by `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customername ORDER BY customername )`

Comment: @Martin Smith: Great idea, tested under Postgres 8.4 and 9.0 with wanted result.

Comment: @markus - I should probably add it as an answer then!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SELECT  customername
FROM    TEST
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY customername ORDER BY customername )
```

Comment: I used this instead of Order By but Its working very slow.