# Android SQLite query order issue

Tags: java, android, sql, database, sqlite

How can I query a database to display a table with data by two different IDs, yet alternate each ID per row and yet still order by time. For example.
Database has 10 Elements of ID1 and 10 Elements of ID2.

I need it to be:

```
ID1 #data #2minutes ago

ID2 #data #15minutes ago

ID1 #data #4minutes ago

ID2 #data #50minutes ago
```

Any Ideas?

UPDATE: The number of ID's must be able to differ from one to n 
and also I am currently trying to do this via the SQLite.query() method.

UPDATE 2: The #data represent columns of data within that row, not just one, so there could be 5 columns for example. Also, The data has to be returned via a cursor.

UPDATE 3: Further elaboration, below is a table and expected result I am trying to achieve.

The input table (Ordered by Time)..

```
id | name | number | time
01   Tim    561481   2 minutes ago
02   Jon    951484   5 minutes ago
02   Jon    978284   7 minutes ago
04   Zen    171484   15 minutes ago
04   Zen    171484   17 minutes ago
03   Ken    468488   20 minutes ago
02   Jon    978284   32 minutes ago
```

And the output: note, I need to alternate the Id's within the data base where possible and yet still order the whole thing by time, for example:

```
id | name | number | time
01   Tim    561481   2 minutes ago
02   Jon    951484   5 minutes ago
04   Zen    171484   15 minutes ago
03   Ken    468488   20 minutes ago
02   Jon    978284   7 minutes ago
04   Zen    171484   17 minutes ago
02   Jon    978284   32 minutes ago
```

**UPDATE 4:** Prefer a very simple solution such as a complex yet clean sql query etc.
**UPDATE 5:** Despite having to give the bounty away, this question still has not been answered with an simple solution to do what I desire.

Comment: Will it be always two IDs?

Comment: So you are asking for the SQL query that achieves that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207867/alternate-results-with-order-by-clause may help

Comment: at-RenanMalkeStigliani No, there may be 4 or maybe 5 different unique ID's, at-Eng.Fouad yes, right now im trying to figure it out via sqlites .query method, but Im not sure how this can be done

Comment: @RNJ I don't believe SQLite supports the `PARTITION` keyword.

Comment: I don't follow the desired ordering: if "the whole thing" is "ordered by time", why does `7 minutes ago` come after `20 minutes ago`? And what exactly do you mean by 'alternate`? That two adjacent rows can never contain the same person?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, it is analogous to this one: how do I sort the last 50 years Tour de France bicycle race by year, showing the country of the victor, but never have the same country appear in adjacent years?  Maybe I've misunderstood, but I think you're asking for the impossible.

Comment: May I point out that it sounds like your data isn't structured very well for how you want to use it.  If your rows are so analogous in two different tables, why aren't they in the same table with a type column?

Comment: I think the idea is to sort by time, clustering rows by each time's rank relative to the times associated with the same ID. That suggests that an SQL window function might be useful; if that's not available, I think you have to go for a nasty triangle join. Another way to do that (in procedural code) would be to split the list of rows by ID into separate lists and sort each one by time. Then take one row from each list, order those rows by time, and put them onto the end of the result set. It's a pretty crazy requirement.

Comment: @Tim Using your Tour de France stats analogy, it would be more like "For every country that has won the Tour de France, tell me what year in which they got their most recent win (ordered by the year descending), then what year they got their second most recent win (ordered by the year descending), and so on." Something like `ORDER BY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Country ORDER BY Year DESC), Year DESC`.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT t.id, t.time, 
    (
        SELECT count(*) 
        FROM tab u 
        WHERE u.id = t.id AND u.time < t.time 
        ORDER BY u.time
    ) counter 
FROM tab t 
ORDER BY counter, t.time
```

I hope I have understood your question correctly.

Output for random data:

```
id  time  counter
2   2   0
0   7   0
4   16  0
1   21  0
3   50  0
2   5   1
1   29  1
0   32  1
4   38  1
3   69  1
2   25  2
1   30  2
0   37  2
4   53  2
2   51  3
4   59  3
0   87  3
4   62  4
2   73  4
0   90  4
```

Don't forget to use indexes.

Comment: Will try this now! :), But what do you mean not to forget to use Indexes ?

Comment: I had to mention about it. For big data set it might be slow. Then read about indexes in sqlite and other optimizations: http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html

Comment: Hey,  I'm trying to get this to work but I'm not sure how to write this via sqlite method, any suggestions?

Comment: I think you actually need a `DESC` on your `time` columns in your `ORDER BY` clauses. "2 minutes ago" is the largest time, not the smallest.

Comment: @rennoDeniro use SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery. To WCWedin: for timestamps you're absolutely right, but I used the same input data as rennoDeniro  which have time difference. To make it work with timestamp you should change `<` to `>` and add DESC for time in ORDERs.

Comment: Okay, I finally got this going, but it's not doing what ive asked. I tried with two unique ID's, and it seems that its just grouping them together...rather than displaying one of each in time order. And also its displaying the oldest in time first...

Comment: So to explain, imagine id1 and id2, as im pulling more information from the database, instead of displaying 2 unique id rows, and then another 2 after the first 2, its just creating two groups, with all ID1s together and all ID2's together

Comment: ? hey you there, I really could use your advice

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:
 1. create SELECT statements for both sets (items with ID1 and items with ID2)
 2. use ORDER BY within those statements for time/IDx order
 3. add a column

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table AS tab2 WHERE tab2.item <= tab1.item) AS rownum
```

4. add list identifiers for both sets 
 5. use a UNION to unite both result sets
 6. select from that united list and compose a field that is built as (rownum||set identifier)
 7. add an ORDER BY the composed field to the whole expression

***Update:*** this was rather intended for two tables; after looking at the example updates above and trying some things I think it's rather hard to code that in a single SQL (using SQLite)

Comment: Since he clarified that he has more than 2 IDs, this can be extended, thus:   "WHERE tab2.item <= tab1.item" could be "WHERE tab2.item <= tab1.item and tab2.ID=tab1.ID"

Comment: Hello, this seems interesting, the only problem is that I am quite new to this field and thus I am completely lost from point 4. and onwards. Could you please elaborate more?

Comment: @rennoDeniro: could you please provide test tables (CREATEs) including data (INSERTs) and expected result? This makes it much easier to give a more precise example of how a potential solution could look like.

Comment: @Andre Hello, thank you for replying, I have updated the answer above and hope you can help, much appreciated

Comment: @rennoDeniro: have you tried my Java code below? I think it wouldn't be as "easy" in SQL (especially with SQLite); good luck!

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
select a, b, c from (
    select a, b, c, rank = row_number() over (order by time) * 2 FROM ID1
    UNION ALL
    select a, b, c, rank = row_number() over (order by time) * 2 + 1 FROM ID2 ) t
order by rank
```

[edit: my bad - not available in SQLite]

Comment: Unfortunately there may be more than 2 unique ID's.. so this wouldn't help

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found it you to perform two queries

First query for the data sorted by ID and Date

```
SELECT ID,
       Date,
       COUNT(1) AS TotalRows
FROM Table
ORDER BY ID, Date
```

And then query the different IDs you have, store it in an array, let's call it `idsArray`

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM Table GROUP BY ID
```

Read all the result from the first query into a Queue: pseudo-code:

```
Queue<YourData> yourQueue = // read it from database cursor

ArrayList sortedData = new ArrayList();

YourData d = null;

String lastId = null;

int position = 0;

while((d = yourQueue.dequeue()) != null) {

    if (lastId == null || d.id.equals(idsArray[position])) {

        sortedData.add(d);

        lastId = d.id;

        if (position < idsArray.length -1) {
            position ++;
        } else {
            position = 0;
        }
    } else {
        yourQueue.enqueue(d);
    }

}
```

Comment: how do I read from the cursor into a list? I need to also put it back into the cursor as my final data is required to be in a cursor

Answer (score 0):

This query will work if the same id may not be possible to have same time.

```
select id, name, rc from
(select id,  name , @rownum:=@rownum+1 as rc from tbl,
(select @rownum:=0) r 
order by (cast(substring(time,1,2) as UNSIGNED)/rc)*cast(ascii(substring(name, 1,1)) as unsigned), time asc) data
```

rownumber calc by [courtecy](http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/09/13/rownum-simulation-with-mysql/)

All I am trying to do is a give a weight factor to each row in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your data seems to be organized very poorly.  If you have multiple tables of seemingly identical data that differ only in type, the data should be stored in one table with a type column instead.

Consider table checkin (id, user, datetime) and table checkout (id, user, datetime) which could be merged into table checkinout (id, user, datetime, inorout).

When the data is structured optimally, you'll find the queries to work on that data are much easier to design.

Also cf. any tutorial on normalization or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: The example is an example, and I never stated that their were multiple tables, thank you anyway